# cannot assign value starting with a quote to another cell in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel-2007, quote

I have an Excel sheet in which a cell is filled by a web query. That cell's content starts with a single quote (`'`). The cell has text number format.

When I use VBA to assign the contents of this cell to another cell, the quote is removed, but I do not want this to happen.

How do I obtain an exact copy of the cell, i.e. quote not removed?

I use:

```
Dim lSourceRange as Range
Dim lTargetRange as Range

set lSourceRange = Cells(1,1)
set lTargetRange = Cells(2,2)

lTargetRange.numberformat = '@'
lTargetRange.value2 = lSourceRange.Value2
```

I also tried

```
lTargetRange.value2 = lSourceRange.text
lTargetRange.value2 = lSourceRange.Value

lTargetRange.value = lSourceRange.text
lTargetRange.value = lSourceRange.Value
```

Always the initial quote is removed. (the value/value2/text of 
`lSourceRange` is `'s-Hertogenbosch`, seen in the debugger as `"'s-Hertogenbosch"`)

I know a quote is to make clear to Excel that I want to use text, but **I need the quote to be part of the value (and the display in the sheet)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lTargetRange.value = "'" & lSourceRange.Value
```

or use this

```
lSourceRange.Copy lTargetRange
```

Comment: This (first solution) indeed show a quote, but now when selecting the cell in the formula bar the value is showed having two single quotes. Selecting the source cell (in which the quote is visible) then in the formula bar also a single single quote is visible

Comment: the second solution using copy seems to do the job. I had some issues with hidding the results using application.screenupdating = false which did not hide everything, but your statement works also in that respect. Thanks @sidd

Comment: Glad it's solved. BTW both methods work. I kinda surprised why are you seeing 2 double quotes in the 1st method.